# How future tense was expressed in PIE?

Tags: proto-indo-european, tense, future

It is known that PIE had no grammatical future tense.

As such, I wonder how future events were expressed in PIE. Whether they used go-periphrasis, desiratives or a form of the root ***bheudh-*** (grow, develop)?

Answer (score 1):

The reference to future was inferred from the context, much like in today's German: Ich arbeite morgen nicht (I won't work tomorrow). The adverb "tomorrow" indicates that the speaker conveys a future event. Without a semantic clue in the sentence, the preceding discourse might be an indication.

The go-periphrasis is a much later development.

Comment: While the disagreement among the daughter languages as to how to form a future certainly strongly implies that there was no future tense, I'm wondering how Atamiri can state this so dogmatically. How do we know what syntax they used?

Comment: What is the evidence that the subjunctive - the PIE general irrealis mood - was not used for the future?